# bones barely moving with mesh

Tags: rigging

I've rigged my mesh, but when I move a bone, it doesnt fully move with it:
[image]

Comment: If the below answers don't work, please let us know what you tried, and more details about what isn't working.

Comment: Just wondering why you would use bone to control the animation on hard surface object. In my opinion bones are more suited for soft object animation like a human arm and legs because there is a weight system that comes along with it to help with softbody deformation. For hard body all you need is a target and animated keys.

Comment: I may want to put it in unreal engine or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the object that is parented with the bone, and go to the data panel [image] in the properties window. Enter edit mode, and select all geometry. Under the *vertex groups*, ensure the *Weight* slider is at `1.000`, and select `Assign`.

[image]

Comment: Not working, http://i.imgur.com/1R0V3Ow.gifv

Comment: Check if you have weights from other bones. if yes set them to 0

Comment: gabe, looking at your video, you don't only need to assign vertices to bones, but also to unassign these same vertices from the others bones. So as wyskoj and @Denis indicate just handle the vertices assignments to the correct bones.

Comment: Lemon, your solution worked, though I'm unable to give you the bounty through comments

Answer (score 0):

Click on the armature that you are using, then without deselecting go down to the mode drop-down, and change that to pose mode.

[image: Weight Paint Mode]

Then select the object that you want to move, and in the mode drop-down, select Weight Paint Mode. Just paint the entire thing red, and it should work correctly. Completely blue means it won't move at all, red means it moves completely with the armature.

This ball I have will become a jumbled mess when I move the armature, because it is only half shaded. If I paint the entire thing red, it will move with the armature correctly, without stretching.

Comment: The image you included isn't helpful at all. You could add an image with the "Weight Paint Mode" visible, or a mesh with either blue or red weights.

Comment: Didn't work, when I checked it wasn't different then first, everything that is needed to be red already is.